# ParallelSSH - SessionHandshakeError when using pssh2_client

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, parallel-processing, gevent

Using [parallel-ssh](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh) module I'm trying to run SSH commands using Natinve Client but getting `SessionHandshakeError`. And if I use Paramiko Client instead, everything works fine. I met the [requirement](http://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#native-client) of `my_pkey.pub` being in the same directory as `my_pkey`.

Here is my code which uses Native Client (changed real IPs to `'ip1'` and `'ip2'`):

```
from pssh.pssh2_client import ParallelSSHClient

pkey = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/my_pkey'
hosts = ['ip1', 'ip2']
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user='root', pkey=pkey)
output = client.run_command('hostname')
for host, host_output in output.items():
    for line in host_output.stdout:
        print(line)
```

Getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 123, in _init
    self.session.handshake(self.sock)
  File "ssh2\session.pyx", line 81, in ssh2.session.Session.handshake
ssh2.exceptions.SessionHandshakeError: ('SSH session handshake failed with error code %s', -5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 123, in _init
    self.session.handshake(self.sock)
  File "ssh2\session.pyx", line 81, in ssh2.session.Session.handshake
ssh2.exceptions.SessionHandshakeError: ('SSH session handshake failed with error code %s', -5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 123, in _init
    self.session.handshake(self.sock)
  File "ssh2\session.pyx", line 81, in ssh2.session.Session.handshake
ssh2.exceptions.SessionHandshakeError: ('SSH session handshake failed with error code %s', -5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NazimokPP/Desktop/AnchorFree/QA-Automation/nodetest/nodetest.py", line 57, in <module>
    main(args.server_domain, args.test_type)
  File "C:/Users/NazimokPP/Desktop/AnchorFree/QA-Automation/nodetest/nodetest.py", line 45, in main
    output = client.run_command('hostname')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\pssh2_client.py", line 182, in run_command
    encoding=encoding, use_pty=use_pty, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\base_pssh.py", line 91, in run_command
    self.get_output(cmd, output)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\base_pssh.py", line 136, in get_output
    (channel, host, stdout, stderr, stdin) = cmd.get()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\greenlet.py", line 482, in get
    self._raise_exception()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\greenlet.py", line 159, in _raise_exception
    reraise(*self.exc_info)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\greenlet.py", line 536, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\pssh2_client.py", line 188, in _run_command
    self._make_ssh_client(host)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\pssh2_client.py", line 313, in _make_ssh_client
    allow_agent=self.allow_agent, retry_delay=self.retry_delay)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 107, in __init__
    THREAD_POOL.apply(self._init)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\pool.py", line 325, in apply
    return self.spawn(func, *args, **kwds).get()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\event.py", line 385, in get
    return self.get(block=False)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\event.py", line 375, in get
    return self._raise_exception()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\event.py", line 355, in _raise_exception
    reraise(*self.exc_info)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 211, in _worker
    value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 126, in _init
    return self._connect_init_retry(retries)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 116, in _connect_init_retry
    return self._init(retries=retries)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 126, in _init
    return self._connect_init_retry(retries)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 116, in _connect_init_retry
    return self._init(retries=retries)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 128, in _init
    raise SessionError(msg, self.host, self.port, ex)
pssh.exceptions.SessionError: ('Error connecting to host %s:%s - %s', 'ip1', 22, SessionHandshakeError('SSH session handshake failed with error code %s', -5))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my code which uses Paramiko Client (changed real IPs to 'ip1' and 'ip2'):

```
from pssh.pssh_client import ParallelSSHClient
from pssh.utils import load_private_key

key_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/my_pkey'
pkey = load_private_key(key_path)
hosts = ['ip1', 'ip2']
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user='root', pkey=pkey)
output = client.run_command('hostname')
for host, host_output in output.items():
    for line in host_output.stdout:
        print(line)
```

And it works. Here's the output (should I care about warnings?):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\ecdsakey.py:202: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: signer and verifier have been deprecated. Please use sign and verify instead.
  signature, ec.ECDSA(self.ecdsa_curve.hash_object())
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py:110: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: signer and verifier have been deprecated. Please use sign and verify instead.
  algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
ip1.hostname
ip2.hostname

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am I doing wrong with Native Client?

Comment: Might be worth trying this from a Linux *client*. From [documentation](http://ssh2-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#pip-binary-packages), Windows builds will use WinCNG rather than OpenSSL for crypto, which has differing implementation and support, further depending on what version of Windows is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was tracked down to the WinCNG back-end used for `libssh2` on Windows - it does not support SHA-256 host key hashes which is now the default in recent versions of OpenSSH server.

The [latest version](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-ssh/) of `parallel-ssh`, `1.6.0`, fixes this issue by switching the Windows back-end to OpenSSL for better compatibility and to match the OSX and Linux binary wheels.

See [release notes](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh/releases/tag/1.6.0) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Some explanations which I got from Panos in Google Groups thread. It didn't help me, but maybe it will be helpful for somebody else.

> A `-5` error is defined as a key exchange error in libssh2. It sounds
>   like the key type is not supported by libssh2 and paramiko shows
>   'ecdsakey.py' being used. ECDSA keys are not currently supported by
>   libssh2 (PR pending).
>
> The warning are from paramiko itself, can't say if they matter.
>
> Better exceptions for native client errors are being worked on for
>   next release.

_

> So for a private key 'my_pkey', there should be a 'my_pkey.pub' in
>   same directory.
>
> It may also be a case of the SSH server's key not being supported by
>   the native client (same limitations as user keys) which would explain
>   the key exchange error. Can check the type of key configured for the
>   server in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, `HostKey` entry. There should be at
>   least one non-ECDSA key configured, eg:
>
> HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
>   HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
>
> If there is only a ECDSA key entry, the native client will not be able
>   to connect.